# Making Prolog's CLPFD aware of permutations and other symmetries

Tags: prolog, permutation, combinatorics, clpfd

`use_module(library(clpfd)).`

CLPFD seems to not be very quick in realizing that in

```
length(L, 9), L ins 1..9, all_distinct(L), foreach(label(L), sum(L, #=, X))
X=45.
```

(I tried `length(L, 4), all_distinct(L), L ins 1..4, sum(L, #=, X), label([X]).` which tries to inform me that `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 7`, so I might be misunderstanding something).

`length(L, 9), L ins 1..9, all_distinct(L), bagof(L, label(L), Ls), length(Ls, X).`

Which should give `X = 362880.` has a similar problem.

Both seem to perform in O(N!) with `length(L, N)`, which is of course because we are enumerating
every possible permutation of `L` to reach our conclusion.

These edge cases could of course be replaced with the simpler solutions we can derive ourself everywhere we use them.
But for example it would be nice to be able have CLPFD be able to reason that in
`length(L, N - 1), L ins 1..N, all_distinct(L)`
we can calculate `sum(L, #=, X)` to have `X in N (N - 1) / 2 - N..N (N - 1) / 2 - 1`.

Am I missing some aspect of CLPFD or a predicate that counts labellings without enumerating them,
and a way to make CLPFD aware of the pigeonhole principle + associativity + commutativity of `sum`,
or do I write predicates for these specific cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SWI Prolog 8.1:

I'm not too knowledgeable you seem "label" too early or too eagerly ("foreach of the labelings" smells fishy)

Try

```
?- length(L, 9), L ins 1..9, all_distinct(L), sum(L, #=, X), X = 45, label(L).
```

Immediately returns with

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
X = 45
```

Similar with

```
?- length(L, 4), all_distinct(L), L ins 1..4, sum(L, #=, X), label(L).
```

which gives

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4],
X = 10 ;
```

I'm not sure what happens here, but again `label([X])` doesn't sound right.

```
?- length(L, 4), all_distinct(L), L ins 1..4, sum(L, #=, X), label([X]).
L = [_7950, _7956, _7962, _7968],
X = 7,
_7950 in 1..4,
_7950+_7956+_7962+_7968#=7,
all_distinct([_7950, _7956, _7962, _7968]),
_7956 in 1..4,
_7962 in 1..4,
_7968 in 1..4 ;
```

I do think CLP(FD) has not noticed that the above solution has no solutions as it outputs the constraints only.

But try

```
?- length(L, 4), all_distinct(L), L ins 1..4, sum(L, #=, X), label([X]), label(L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4],
X = 10
```

Correct.

> But for example it would be nice to be able have CLPFD be able to reason that in length(L, N - 1), L ins 1..N, all_distinct(L) we can calculate sum(L, #=, X) to have X in N (N - 1) / 2 - N..N (N - 1) / 2 - 1.

Definitely general theorem proving over integer arithmetic, rather than constraint propagation. It would be nice but I don't think it goes that far.

Comment: You are right and I seem to have not yet grasped the effect of reordering clauses, giving `X=45` is a weird way of trying to prove `X=45` though.

Comment: foreach labeling was a desperate attempt to get an actual proof. `label([X]), label(L)` has the same effect as just `label(L)` while taking longer. It is unfortunate that `length(L, 4), all_distinct(L), L ins 1..5, sum(L, #=, X)` doesn't directly lead to `X in 10..14` but using `length(L, 4), all_distinct(L), L ins 1..5, sum(L, #=, X), labeling([min(X)], [X]), label(L).` and `max(X)` is not too bad